# Symfony imap "Attempted to call function "imap_open" from the global namespace."

Tags: php, symfony, imap, symfony-3.2

Im trying to get imap working inside my symfony 3 project. But when im trying to run any imap related commands I get the `"Attempted to call function "imap_function_here" from the global namespace."` error. I'm pretty sure that I am using it correctly because if I run an completely empty php file with just:

```
<?php
$conn = \imap_open('imap.mailserver.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX','mail@mailserver.com', 'password');
var_dump($conn)
```

It work just fine, but the exact same code inside my symfony project wil result in an error. Can anyone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if we don't get any context? Where does the error occur? How does your configuration for swiftmailer look?

Comment: the problem is that imap_open is a native php function and it work just fine when used outside symfony but when i place it anywhere inside my project it doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after 3 hours of failing I restarted my server and it works. My symfony was running while I installed imap so it started without it. So thanks for the effort, but it just was a stupid mistake on my side.